# About Navigation among xaml pages

Tags: xaml, navigation

I added a new xaml page named 'categories.xaml' to my project in visual studio 2010 express for windows phone.The page was to be navigated from mainpage.xaml by clicking a button.

I wrote the following code in the button click event(using C#):-

this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("categories.xaml",UriKind.Relative));

but it didn't work so i replaced it with the following code:-

this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/categories.xaml",UriKind.Relative));

and it worked.

What is the problem with the 1st line of code?And also when i didn't wrote 'this' the application ran.What's the use of 'this'?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two code is that the second code has a forward slash. Now, the use of forward slash is to indicate that the content is local to the Xap file. Failure to include the leading slash will result in an ArgumentException (details below) being thrown

The word this in the "this.NavigationService.Navigate" refers to the current instance of the class. In this case you are pointing to the class of your categories.xaml.